# How to insert data while copy a column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to insert data while copying a column.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO transactions
(order_id,cart_id,full_name,email,phone,street1,street2, 
 city,state,zip_code,country,landmark,sub_total,tax,grand_total,
 description,txn_type,paid,customer_id,items)
 VALUES
('$order_id','$cart_id','$full_name','$email','$phone','$street1','$street2',
 '$city','$state','$zip_code','$country','$landmark','$sub_total','$tax',
 '$grand_total','$description','$txn_type','$paid','$customer_id', items 
  FROM cart WHERE id ='$cart_id')
 ");
```

In the above code, I am inserting all the values while copying

```
"items from cart where id=$cart_id".
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get as error message ..?

Answer (score 1):

seems you need  an insert select

```
insert  into  transactions 
(order_id,cart_id,full_name,email,phone,street1,street2, 
   city,state,zip_code,country,landmark,sub_total,tax,grand_total,
   description,txn_type,paid,customer_id,items)
  SELECT 
 '$order_id','$cart_id','$full_name','$email','$phone','$street1','$street2',
 '$city','$state','$zip_code','$country','$landmark','$sub_total','$tax',
 '$grand_total','$description','$txn_type','$paid','$customer_id', items 
  FROM cart WHERE id ='$cart_id'
```

bust you should not  use php var in sql  you are at risk for sqlinjection  .. you should take a look at you mysql driver for prepared statements and binding param  ..

Comment: php variable in sql? I dont understand. Kindly elaborate so that I can learn I am not aware of that.

Comment: $order_id, $cart_id ,,,  and so on ... are php variables .. that you are  using in  SQL command ..could be that these values come from usr input and could contain malicious  code  .. ... you can take a look at sqlinjection  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
VALUES(
```

with

```
( SELECT
```

Just refer  [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)